# A question about convergence of $b_n=f\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f(x)$ is some function with domain [0,1] and $\sum_{n\ge1}f\left(\frac 1n\right)$ converges,
than $a_n=f\left(\frac 1n\right)\to 0$ but does $b_n=f\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)$ also converge to zero ?
I could not prove the last statement or find any counter-example,
I only guess that since nothing known about $f(x)$ there may be some counter-example.

Could you give me some hint how to solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: The numbers of the shape $\frac{1}{n^2}$ are an infinite *subsequence* of the numbers of the shape $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: So, if $f\left(\frac 1n \right)\to 0$ than $f\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)\to 0$ also ?

Comment: Yes, it approaches $0$. Note that this does not in general imply that $\sum f(1/n^2)$ converges.

Comment: @AndréNicolas True, but in this case, it does because $f$ is positive...

Comment: That depends on the interpretation of "function on $[0,1]$." If it means function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, sure. If it just means function with domain $[0,1]$, then not necessarily.

Comment: Function on [0,1] means function with domain [0,1].

Answer (score 0):

Are you wondering if the second series is necessarily convergent? If $f(x) >= 0$ your series is absolutely convergent and hence every subsequence also converges. What if the sign of $f(x)$ varies with $x$? Can you make the series conditionally convergent and the second series divergent?

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is always positive (or always negative) we have

$$\infty >| \sum_{n=1}^t f \left(\frac{1}{n} \right)| \ge | \sum_{n=1}^{[\sqrt{t} ]} f \left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right) |$$ where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.

But if $f$ is not always of the same sign, let

$f \left(\frac{1}{n^2 +1} \right)=-\left(\frac{1}{n +1} \right)$

$f \left(\frac{1}{n^2 } \right)= \left(\frac{1}{n } \right)$ and

$f\left(\frac{1}{k} \right)=0$ for $ (n+1)^2 > k > n^2+1$

and we have $ \sum_{n \ge 1} f \left(\frac{1}{n} \right)= \sum_{n \ge 1} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n}= \ln 2$

but  $\sum_{n=1}^{t} f \left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right) \to \infty$

This is a theorem that you will find in your book either when you were introduced to sequences or when you were introduced to subsequences, somewhere before the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem:

As for your first question, if $a_n \longrightarrow_{n \to \infty} l$ then for every injective increasing sequence $n(k) :\mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ we have $a_{n(k)} \longrightarrow_{k \to \infty} l$.

Now just substitute $a_n= f(1/n)$, $n(k)=k^2$, $l=0$